# Need to show User count other data count on Django admin interface

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-admin

I've created custom index.html for django admin. Here is the ScreeenShot
[image]

Here count of user or model 1 is static. I want to update from database. Is there any way to pass variable from admin.py to main Admin interface?

Is there any way to change in index just like we can do with some model : -

```
class UserAdmin(DjangoUserAdmin):
"""Define admin model for custom User model with no email field."""

fieldsets = (
    (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
    (_('Personal info'), {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name','Mobile_number','Address','avatar','AI','U_ID')}),
    (_('Permissions'), {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser',
                                   'groups', 'user_permissions')}),
    (_('Important dates'), {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}),
)
add_fieldsets = (
    (None, {
        'classes': ('wide',),
        'fields': ('email', 'password1', 'password2'),
    }),
)
list_display = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_staff','Mobile_number','Address','avatar','AI','U_ID')
search_fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name','Mobile_number','Address','avatar','AI','U_ID')
ordering = ('email',)
```

Comment: share your code what have you tried

Comment: @AnjaneyuluBatta I really don't know how to change in Admin index to be honest. I've updated question though - admin.py

Comment: where you are using the template `index.html` ?

Comment: @AnjaneyuluBatta admin/index.html

Answer (score 3):

One idea is to use **custom** `context-processor`. You can add a new context processor like this:

```
# in context_processor.py

def user_count(request):
   return { 'total_user' : User.objects.all().count() }
```

register it in `settings.py` inside `TEMPLATE` configurations:

```
   'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            'your_app.context_processor.user_count'
        ],
    },
```

Use it inside template:

```
<div>
    {{ user_count }}
</div>
```

#### FYI

`context-processor` is helpful when you want to show same data in every single template. But if this data is only for one page and maybe needs to send extra context data via modeladmin, then [change_view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.history_view) is more suited for this. For example(copy pasted from documentation):

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    change_form_template = 'admin/myapp/extras/openstreetmap_change_form.html'

    def get_osm_info(self):
        pass

    def change_view(self, request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        extra_context = extra_context or {}
        extra_context['osm_data'] = self.get_osm_info()
        return super().change_view(
            request, object_id, form_url, extra_context=extra_context,
        )
```

Comment: That helped thanks, man. But do you think this is genuine way to pass variables? I have to add some graphs and some other tables as well, So should I make the context processor for everything or there are some other ways as well.